# Using JavascriptExecutor to add an element in IE

Tags: javascript, href

I am using Selenium and Java to automate testing a web page which has a link that you click which opens a pdf file.  This has to be done in IE unfortunately, for some reason.  What I do is dump the page source to a file, and load it with Chrome which is much easier to debug. We need to examine the PDF file for certain fields.  We have all the tools we need to get the text from a pdf file.  That is not the problem.  The problem is getting the file so that our Java code has access to it.

We have a method someone wrote on file downloads, to save the file and return the file name.  However, this is when a file is downloaded, but in this case the file is open in a new window.

I looked at the html. Here is the relevant part:

```
 <td onclick="spawnLetter();" style="CURSOR: hand" width="45" align="left">
    <img border="0" src="/images/icon_file.gif" width="17" height="17"> 
 </td>
```

spawnLetter() basically opens a window and displays the file.  Someone has found out how to get the name of the file.  It is in the page source:

```
            int imageTemp = pageSource.indexOf("imagetemp");
            int pdfLocation = pageSource.indexOf(".pdf");
            String pdfUrl = StringUtils.join(pageSource.substring(imageTemp, pdfLocation), ".pdf");
```

I want an href I can download.  I tried adding it to the /img tag but I guess that can't take an href.  So I  found a way using javascriptexecutor to add an element.  I got the td element above and called it parent:

```
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String script = "var p = document.createElement('a');p.setAttribute('href','_HREF_');p.setAttribute('name','welcomePacket');p.setAttribute('download',''); p.setAttribute('target','_blank'); arguments[0].appendChild(p);";
            script = script.replace("_HREF_", pdfUrl);
            js.executeScript(script, parent);
```

Now, JavascriptExecutor is pretty unforgiving.  Any error in the script and it will throw an error.  This did not throw an error so I assume that means it added the element.  However, when I look at the page source I cannot see the element, and it I do a

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='welcomePacket']"))
```

it does not find the element.  I tried refreshing the page but that did not work.

Is there something else that needs to be done, like a setVisible() or something?  Or why is the new element not being found?

Comment: At `js.executeScript(script, parent);` where do you define the `parent`?

Comment: //img[@src='/images/icon_file.gif'] -- this is the click element.  Parent is clickEle.findElement(By.xpath("./.."))

Comment: ok.  working now.

Comment: nice to hear. Would you mind answering your own question with the solution. So other user with the same Problem have a chance of solving it. Thanks.